# Testing with Rspec gives uncomplete messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I´m testing my rails app using rspec and remarkable.

I have the following spec

```
describe Trade do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:type) }
end
```

when I run it I get the failure

```
'Trade should require {{attributes}} to be set' FAILED
```

The failure itself is right once my validations are not yet implemented but why didn´t rspec replaced {{attributes}} by type?

Env.:

Rails: 2.3.9

Ruby: 1.8.7

Windows Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your remarkable locale file just replace all the {{}}'s with %{}.